# Terminology: what is the correct word for the quantity of "association" between x value and classes

Tags: classification, terminology

I am looking for a word for the quantity of "association" between a variable x value and a classification class.

For example, let's imagine we have two two classes $A$ and $B$ and two inputs $\mathbf{x}_A$ and $\mathbf{x}_B$ from each class respectively. The probability of membership in each class varies roughly linearly between these two inputs. I want a word to say the "association" of the input $\mathbf{x}_C = a \mathbf{x}_A + b \mathbf{x}_B$ with $A$ is determined by $a$ and $b$.

I initially used the word "correlation" without considering it, but then I realised this is not correct.

Other usage examples:

- Feature $i$ has a negative "association" with class $A$
- We may add vector $\mathbf{u}$ because it is "unassociated" with the output classes.
- Transformation $f$ preserves "association" with the output class.
- Removing noise increases output class "association".

I could say "probability of membership", but that would make certain phrases awkward. For example "Feature $i$ has a negative contribution to the probability of membership of class $A$". I would much rather say something similar to "Feature $i$ has a negative correlation with class $A$".

Comment: percentage factor maybe?

Comment: membership factor?

Comment: @NikosM. thanks for the suggestions. Are these standard terms? I would like to use a standard term if that is possible.

Comment: The term factor along with a qualification for specialisation is standard. The qualification is chosen to fit your context